# Reload PageController does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fecthing data from the service as follows, but pagecontroller is not getting refreshed.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.nElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.nTempElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadFromURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                             [self 
                                              viewControllerAtIndex:0]]               
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
  });
}

-(void)loadFromURL {

    if([self.nElements count]){
        [self.nElements removeAllObjects];
    }
    if([self.nTempElements count]){
        [self.nTempElements removeAllObjects];
    }

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://www.xxxxx.com.tr/api/news.json" parameters:nil progress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
        if(responseObject != NULL) {
            for ( id jsonItem in [responseObject valueForKey:@"news"])
            {
                MainNewsData *dicItem = [[MainNewsData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
                [self.nElements addObject:dicItem];
                [self.nTempElements addObject:[jsonItem valueForKey:@"resim"]];
            }
        }


    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
}
```

Comment: Try putting the `setViewControllers` method in main thread.

Comment: I have updated based on your feedback, but it is still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should call function in Main Thread as -Ganesh- said.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                             [self 
                                              viewControllerAtIndex:0]]               
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
  });
```

Comment: I have updated based on your feedback, but it is still same issue.